Non-noetherian schemes with noetherian underlying space (in the Zariski topology)
I am curious if there are many non-Noetherian schemes with Noetheiran underlying space.
I know an example, we consider: $R= k[x_1, x_2, \dots]/\langle x_1^2, x_2^2, \dots\rangle $ for $k$ a field. Then its spectrum is a point but its not a Noetheiran ring. This example seems rather degenerate.
I am curious if there is a larger class of examples.

You can easily produce more examples replacing $k$ with any Noetherian ring. I haven't thought about this much but I would be curious if there are examples where the scheme is additionally reduced. This may be easy but at least it's a concrete question one can ask.

The spectrum of a 1-dim local ring $R$ has two points as a topological space (and is homeomorphic to the Sierpinski space), and so is minimal in being the underlying space of a 1-dim scheme. This works for $R$ Noetherian or not. Generalizing this idea to dim > 1 is possible, but requires $R$ non-Noetherian (I haven't a proof). So for example you can exhibit a 2-dim ring $R_2$, whomst spectrum has exactly 3 points and is totally ordered by specialization/generization. Extending these ideas, you can get $n$-dim affine scheme with $n+1$ points, necess. non-Noetherian (if n > 1).

One common class of examples come from perfections of $\mathbf{F}_p$-schemes. To explain this, let's give a brief summary of how perfection works.
Let $p$ be a prime number and let $X$ be an $\mathbf{F}_p$-scheme. Write $F\colon X \to X$ for the absolute Frobenius: on underlying spaces, $F$ is the identity, and on structure sheaves $F$ is given by $a \mapsto a^p$. See [Stacks, Tag 0CC6]. The absolute Frobenius is a universal homeomorphism [Stacks, Tag 0CC8], in particular, $F$ is affine [Stacks, Tag 04DE].
Definition. An $\mathbf{F}_p$-scheme $X$ is perfect if the absolute Frobenius $F\colon X \to X$ is an isomorphism.
Definition. The perfection of an $\mathbf{F}_p$-scheme $X$ is the cofiltered limit
$$ X^{\mathrm{perf}} := \mathrm{lim} \Big( \cdots
\xrightarrow{F} X \xrightarrow{F} X \xrightarrow{F} \cdots \Big) \rlap{\ .}$$
Notes.

Since the absolute Frobenius is affine, this limit exists in the category of schemes [Stacks, Tag 01YX]. Moreover, if $X$ is affine, then $X^{\mathrm{perf}}$ is affine.
Since the absolute Frobenius is a universal homeomorphism, the natural morphism $X^{\mathrm{perf}} \to X$ is a universal homeomorphism. In particular, if $X$ is Noetherian, then $X^{\mathrm{perf}}$ has Noetherian underlying space.
The scheme $X^{\mathrm{perf}}$ is perfect. Moreover, the assignment $X \mapsto X^{\mathrm{perf}}$ defines a right adjoint to the inclusion of perfect $\mathbf{F}_p$-schemes into all $\mathbf{F}_p$-schemes.

The following simple example demonstrates that even when $X$ is Noetherian, $X^{\mathrm{perf}}$ is often non-Noetherian.
Example. Let $X = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{F}_p[t])$ be the affine line. Then $X^{\mathrm{perf}}$ is affine with corresponding ring
$$\mathbf{F}_p[t]^{\mathrm{perf}} \cong \mathbf{F}_p[t^{1/p^{\infty}}] := \frac{\mathbf{F}_p[t,x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots]}{\Big ( t-x_1^p,x_1-x_2^p,x_2-x_3^p,\ldots \Big)} \rlap{\ .} $$
The ring $\mathbf{F}_p[t^{1/p^{\infty}}]$ is not Noetherian, even though its spectrum is homeomorphic to $\mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{F}_p}^1$.
Remark. Section 3 of Bhatt and Scholze's Projectivity of the Witt vector affine Grassmannian is a great place to read about perfection.

The answer of Peter Haine would be one of my go-to choices, but I think another would be schemes over something like $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/p^n$ (or analogues for other non-discrete rank $1$ valuation rings).
Rigid geometry deals with (as a special case) the analogue of complex analytic varieties but over a non-archimedean field $K$. One of the most powerful techniques for studying such objects is to use the idea of Raynaud, that "rigid spaces over $K$ are the localization of formal schemes over $\mathcal{O}_K$". Let me not try to make this meaning precise here (one can consult the book by Fujiwara--Kato for more information), but suffice it to say that this perspective brings the study of formal schemes over $\mathcal{O}_K$ squarely into the "need-to-understand" category. Of course, the data of a formal scheme $\mathfrak{X}$ over $\mathcal{O}_K$ can be thought about as equivalent to the data of the $\mathbb{N}$-system of schemes $\mathfrak{X}_n=\mathfrak{X}_{\mathcal{O}_K/\varpi^n}$, where $\varpi$ is an element of $K$ with $0<|\varpi|<1$. So, one is inexorably led to the study of finite-type schemes over $\mathcal{O}_K/\varpi^n$.
Now, if $K$ is a discretely valued field (e.g., $\mathbb{Q}_p$) then $\mathcal{O}_K/\varpi^n$ is Noetherian. But, even if one is mostly interested in such $K$, geometric arguments often require moving to algebraically closed non-archimedean fields $L$ (e.g., $\mathbb{C}_p$), and for such $L$ one has that $\mathcal{O}_L/\varpi^n$ is not Noetherian. Thus, a finite type scheme $S$ over $\mathcal{O}_L/\varpi^n$ will also not be Noetherian. But, if $\kappa$ is the residue field of $L$, then $S$ is a nil-thickening of $S_\kappa$ which, being finite type over $\kappa$, is Noetherian. As nil-thickenings do not change the underlying topological space, we see that $S$ is not Noetherian, but is topologically Noetherian.

You are missing a word after "inexorable". Not a big deal, but you might want to be more careful in the future.

This is a long comment to Peter Haine's answer, showing how often the perfection is non-Noetherian:
Proposition. Every Noetherian (semi)perfect $\mathbb F_p$-algebra is a finite product of perfect fields of char $p$.
This should be well-known, but I do not find a reference.
First, an surjective endomorphism of a Noetherian ring is necessarily an isomorphism by [SP, Tag 06RN], thus semiperfectness implies perfectness for Noetherian $\mathbb F_p$-algebras.
Lemma. Let $R$ be a Noetherian perfect $\mathbb F_p$-algebra. Then

The Jacobson radical $\DeclareMathOperator\Rad{Rad}\Rad(R)$ is zero.
If $R$ is an integral domain, then $R$ is a perfect field of char $p$.

Proof of the lemma. Let $x\in R$ be any element. Consider the chain
$$
(x)\subseteq(x^{1/p})\subseteq(x^{1/p^2})\subseteq\dots\subseteq(x^{1/p^r})\subseteq\cdots
$$
of ideals of $R$. Since the ring $R$ is Noetherian, this chain stabilizes at some point, say $(x^{1/p^r})=(x^{1/p^{r+1}})$ for some $r\in\mathbb N$. Let $y:=x^{1/p^{r+1}}$. Then there exists an element $a\in R$ such that $ay^p=y$.

For every $x\in\Rad(R)$, and $y$ as above, then $y$ lies in the Jacobson radical $\Rad(R)$ as well. It follows that $1-ay^{p-1}\in R$ is invertible, and thus $y=0$, so $x=0$.
For every non-zero element $x$ in $R$, the element $y$ is a non-zero-divisor, which implies that $ay^{p-1}=1$, and thus $y$ is invertible, so $x$ is invertible as well, Q.E.D.

Proof of the Proposition. Let $R$ be a Noetherian perfect $\mathbb F_p$-algebra. Applying the lemma to $R/\mathfrak p$ for minimal prime ideals $\mathfrak p\subseteq R$, we see that the Krull dimension of $R$ is zero, thus the Noetherian ring $R$ is Artinian, and consequently, it is a finite product of Artinian local rings. We apply the lemma again, seeing that each Artinian local ring factor has zero Jacobson radical, thus they are perfect fields of char $p$, Q.E.D.

Thanks for writing this up! Maybe it is worth mentioning that one can replace "noetherian perfect $\mathbf{F}_p$-algebra" with "noetherian perfect $\mathbf{F}_p$-scheme". That is, every noetherian perfect $\mathbf{F}_p$-scheme is affine. If $X$ is such a scheme, then since $\mathrm{dim}(X)$ is the supremum of the dimensions of all affine opens in $X$, and the dimension of a product of fields is $0$, by the result in the affine case, we deduce that  $\mathrm{dim}(X)=0$. To conclude, note that by Serre's cohomological characterization of affineness, every $0$-dimensional qcqs scheme is affine.
